# iPhone Safari making a phone call

Tags: html, iphone, safari, tel

Is there something I can put in the code for an HTML page I am making for Safari on iPhone to make a call when clicked on? Something similar to:

```
<a href="tel://1300111222">click to call</a>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to remove // from your link, that is `<a href="tel:1300111222">click to call</a>`

Answer (score 8):

As Nava answered, remove // from your link.

But if you are using same web-application for desktop as well as mobile, then this won't work for your desktop and when you click on link, page will gone to "tel:XXXXXXXX". So this idea became fail.

Try using "callto" instead of "tel" like this

```
<a href='callto:1300111222'>Click to call</a>
```

Then if you are using mobile browser, then it will show call prompt and if you are using windows browser, then it will prompt you to call with "Skype" and any other related application.

Comment: thanks Rohit. You really dig that question out of the grave :)