# onClick - call phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL Scheme for Phone Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009181/url-scheme-for-phone-call)
>   [iphone safari making phone call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649529/iphone-safari-making-phone-call)

I am using the code below on a mobile site but when somebody clicks I don't want them directed to a new page I want a phone number to be called. Is this possible using the onClick function?

```
<div class="button left" id="map" onClick="window.location='#'"><span class="bottom">Call us now</span></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You should rather use something like

```
<a href="tel:[phone number]"><span class="bottom">Call us now</span></a>
```